# Using python psychopg2 to get a count on all variables in the database that contain a specific string

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, python-3.x, postgresql-9.4

I have a list, words = [word1, word2, word3, ...]
I want to use sql to return the number of times each word appears in Column A of an sql file.  I can't figure out how to pass a variable into my sql query.  Any help would be appreciated!  My code so far looks like:

```
import psycopg2 as sql

for word in words

   conn = sql.connect(**params)
   c = conn.cursor()   


   #Create query and parameters to get usernames and ids 
   Query = """ SELECT COUNT(Column A) FROM file
            WHERE Column A SIMILAR TO '% **VARIABLE WORD** %'

            LIMIT 1000; """


   try:
       c.execute(Query)

   except:
       conn.commit()
       print("Error in Query")

   Result = c.fetchall()
```

Also, will this count return the total number of times the word appears or just the number of lines of column A in which it appears?  (Will the count of the in "the team won the game" return one or two?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The replaceable parameter flag used by psycopg2 is "%s", and to use a plain "%" in a query with replaceable parameters you need to double it (i.e., "%%").  So your code should look like:

```
 Query = """SELECT COUNT(Column_A) FROM file
        WHERE Column_A SIMILAR TO '%%%s%%'
        LIMIT 1000;"""
try:
   c.execute(Query, word)
```

This should return the number of lines in which the word appears, not the total number of occurrences of the word in all lines.

Your example has a space in the column name used; I've substituted an underscore, but if the column name really contains a space, the name should be double-quoted in this query.